# XSLT not contains multiple String

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, conditional-statements

In XSLT, is it possible to do condition check like:

```
<xsl:if test='node != contains("Apple, Banana, Carrot")'>..</xsl>
```

So, if the node have the following string it will not view in the list.
the contains(..) string dynamically created.

For instance..

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <node>Apple</node>
    <node>Banana</node>
    <node>Carrot</node>
    <node>Dog</node>
    <node>Elephant</node>
    <node>Fox</node>
    <node>Golf</node>
</list>
```

the **contains("<% script %>")** - sorry the code will not work here. But it will just add a string separated by comma.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Where will this "string separated by comma" come from? Can it be hard-coded in the stylesheet? If yes, why must it be in the form of a comma-separated string, and not in the form of the expression suggested?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you need to express the requirement more clearly. Trying to tell us what you want by using made-up syntax isn't a good specification technique. Do you mean "if the set of nodes does not contain any of the following strings" or "if the set of nodes does not contain all of the following strings" or perhaps something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use three predicates:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(text(),'Apple')) or contains(text(),'Banana')) or contains(text(),'Carrot'))">..</xsl>
```

---

**Referring to your updated question:**

Naming your keyword file `keyword.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <node>Apple</node>
    <node>Banana</node>
    <node>Carrot</node>
    <node>Dog</node>
    <node>Elephant</node>
    <node>Fox</node>
    <node>Golf</node>
</list>
```

and an arbitrary data test file `data.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <a>Apple</a>
    <b>Carrot</b>
    <c>Crap</c>
</Data>
```

you can get the desired nodes using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="inc" select="document('keyword.xml')/list" />

  <xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />      <!-- only for debugging/output purposes -->
    <xsl:variable name="cur" select="text()" />
    <xsl:if test="$inc/node/text()[contains(., $cur)]">..</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The essential expression is

```
$inc/node/text()[contains(., $cur)]
```

which checks if the current `text()` node saved by the `<xsl:variable...>` expression is contained in the `keyword.xml` file under `list/node/text()`.

So in this test case the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    a..
    b..
    c
```

Comment: uhm..not possible sir @zx485 the contains string are populated dynamically. So possible it will added more strings

Comment: @mrrsb: Pardon me, I do not understand what your asking for.

Comment: @mrrsb Please edit your question and provide a **complete** example, including the source of the "dynamic" strings - see: [mcve].

Comment: wow! that's quick! now its easy for me to get that string! kudos sir @zx485